# Excel 2013 not showing form command

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi have a large amount of data input I need to do using Excel (not my choice). I want to use the data entry form as described [here](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/create-data-entry-form-excel/). However, for some reason I do not have the `Form` command available in the list as shown in Step 4 in the tuorial:

[image]

I'm using Excel Office 365 Version 1706.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to find the command using the search function in the Ribbon:

[image]